# Add transport type when showing Directions on map

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps, mapkit

How can I add transport type when showing Directions on map
I have used this code so far, but it is showing Walking distance on map

```
NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=%f,%f&daddr=%f,%f"];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:URL];
```

Comment: have you solve your problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add one extra param **directionsmode** for different direction mode like below :

```
NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=%f,%f&daddr=%f,%f&directionsmode=transit"];
```

There are many types of direction mode :

- driving
- transit
- bicycling
- walking

Also you can use URLSchema for open app with schema like below Google Map Guide

**Google Map URLSchema Guide :** https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/urlscheme

Comment: Let me check..Thanks for your answer!

Comment: Not actually for my Lat long it is showing No Routes Found.

Comment: Ok so that location have no routes so thats why its not showing all related options. anyway thanks for reply hope my provided answer will useful in future if you required same, Thanks.